# Excel 2013 - removing LegendEntry objects from a PivotChart Legend using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, charts, pivot-chart

I've got a PivotChart which typically shows 6-8 series out of a possible 15, many of which tend to be zero. So every time it refreshes, it has 15 series and the Legend only needs to list the series with non-zero figures, to keep the chart uncluttered and easy to read.

I'm attempting to use **VBA** to delete particular items wherever the series is all zero (maximum value = 0), and encountered more issues than expected:

1. I'm looping through every item from the Chart's *FullSeriesCollection*, going forward through the list of series one by one. However, as the Legend is a separate object from the Series, **you can't use the current series from my loop to refer to it, and so require a loop counter**.
2. **There is no way to find out the name/value of a LegendEntries item**, so you have to match Series with the Legend without being able to confirm which LegendEntries item is which.

*(apparently the below feature is present in Excel 2007 onwards?)*

3. It appears that the FullSeriesCollection object orders the items (sensibly) from 1 to 13 as you loop through them, but **the LegendEntries object orders items in reverse, from <s>13 to 1</s>**.
4. The LegendEntries object begins its index at 0, so **its items are actually ordered from 12 to 0**.
5. **The LegendEntries object re-numbers its items as you delete from it**.
   So when you delete item 1, all the items in the list re-number from 11 to 0.
6. **I need to refresh the chart every time the PivotTable updates**, to re-capture all deleted LegendEntries items which may now be non-zero.

In light of these complications, I've really struggled to delete the specific items which I need to remove from the chart.

**How do you effectively loop through a PivotTable's items and delete corresponding LegendEntries series wherever the items are all-zero?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Begin with the Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate event

The worksheet which houses the PivotTable needs the following code, so it calls the new function 'RefreshAbsenceLabels' in Module 1 whenever this specifically **named** PivotTable is refreshed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

If Target.Name = "This Specific Table" Then

    Module1.RefreshAbsenceLabels
    MsgBox "The PivotTable has been updated."

End If

End Sub
```

---

### Talk to the right chart, and refresh its Legend

```
Public Function RefreshAbsenceLabels()

Set DaysAbsent = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("Department Absences")

With DaysAbsent.Chart

    If .HasLegend Then
        .HasLegend = False
    End If
    .HasLegend = True
```

---

### Set up your counter, and set it to the count of the series minus one

*the minus one is to account for the fact that the FullSeriesCollection is numbered 1 to X, whilst the LegendEntries items are numbered X-1 to 0*

```
    Dim x As Integer
    x = .FullSeriesCollection.Count - 1
```

---

### Loop through Series, deleting corresponding LegendEntries items

*Counter loops down towards zero. The advantage of the LegendEntries' reverse numbering is that you don't have to offset for missing items every time you delete things: any renumbered items have already been dealt with, and it no longer matters what number they are.*

***Application.WorksheetFunction.Max*** finds the highest value from the series

```
    For Each ser In .FullSeriesCollection

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ser.Values) = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Deleting" & ser.Name & " - " & x
            .Legend.LegendEntries(x).Delete
        End If

        x = x - 1
    Next
End With
End Function
```